# Return php script with .load jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So i have been trying to search around, bu I can't seem to find a good example trying to do the same.
Here is the scenario:
I have a page (php and html) that runs a included php script (currentMonth.php) when its loaded.
On the page i have a  that should replace the content that currentMonth.php generated with content from another script, previousMonth.php

The scripts themselves only change 2 variables, which are used in a larger script (Google Calendar Api).
The scripts look like this:

CurrentMonth.php

```
<?php
require_once 'getEvents.php';   

if(isset($_SESSION['eventMonth'])) {
    $dateMonth = $_SESSION['eventMonth'];

}else {
    $currentDate = date(DateTime::ATOM);
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", $currentDate);
    $dateMonth = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", $currentDate)->format("n");
}
$month = $dateMonth;
$monthStart = $month -1;
$_SESSION['eventMonth'] = $month;
getEvents($monthStart, $month);

?>
```

The previousMonth.php script simply subracts the months by 1 instead.

Now to the actual problem:
I want to be able to run the script without reloading the page (AJAX).
As far as i could see the jQuery function .load() would fit fine.
However the problem is that nothing is returned. I have checked the log in my browser and the request is made, but it doesn't replace the data. The jQuery looks like this:

```
function previousMonth() {

    $('#events').load('/paycheck/scripts/previousMonth.php');

}
```

The function is called with an inline onclick() event in the

On the jQuery Documentation it states that .load() returns the html from the loaded script.
The content gereated by my getEvents scripts returns html with injected php like so:

```
<div class="event-container">
            <div class="eventBody">
                    <span class="eventIcon"><div id="iconHolder"></div></span>
                    <span class="name"><?php echo $event->summary; ?></a></span>
                    <span class="date"><?php echo $newday; echo('. '); echo $newmonth;  ?></span>
                    <span class="time"><?php echo $newTimeStr; echo(' - '); echo $newTimeEnd; ?></span>
                    <span class="diff"><?php echo($count); ?></span>
                    <span class="pay"><?php echo(round($final,2)); ?></span>
                    <span class="more"><p id="expand">Mere info<p></span>
            </div>
</div>
```

So to get to the actual question. 
Im pretty sure that i have misunderstood something here, but i guess that im pretty blind at this point.
So how can i use jQuery and AJAX to run a php script, which returns a html body and then replace the current displayed content with the new one?
**EDIT**
getEvents.php
This script gets the information form the Google Api and then calculates some payments. These are stored in variables that are then echo'ed inside the html body.

**Update 1**
The content from the script should display in this

```
<div id="events">
    <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/paycheck/scripts/currentMonth.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not the solution, but will need to add `session_start()` at the beginning of your PHP script.

Comment: where do you call `previousMonth()`

Comment: By the way you said `getEvents($monthStart, $month);`? returns the HTML, but when do you `echo` it?

Comment: session_start() is used at the top of the main php page.

Comment: previousMonth is called from a <div> on the main page with an onclick event.

Comment: I never use the echo function in getEvents. i contains the html body above. If you were to load the scripts (which you cant alone) it would show a html body. Should I echo it?

Comment: Yes give echo getEvents.... a try :)

Comment: echoing does not seem to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the reason behind .load() not returning the data, but i used .get() instead like so:

```
function previousMonth() {
    $.get( "/paycheck/scripts/previousMonth.php", function( data ) {
      $( "#events" ).html( data );
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });

}
```

And it now returns the data correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you can navigate to CurrentMonth.php in your browser and it displays the desired HTML ('.event-container' and it's contents) then you should be able to use $.load() to retrieve and display it. What does the getEvents() function do? Does it return HTML or does it echo out? If it returns the HTML, you'll have to replace `getEvents($monthStart, $month);` with `echo getEvents($monthStart, $month);`. If you only want it echoing with the AJAX call, you can wrap this in a clause. My favorite is:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === true && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    // Your AJAX-specific code here
}
```

Best practice would be to have a separate PHP file that handles AJAX. This file could simply `include('CurrentMonth.php');` and have it echo the contents with methods listed above.

Comment: I checked and currenMonth.php returns html when visited.

Comment: using echo getEvents($monthStart, $month); does not seem to fix the issue

Comment: Please update your question with a snippet of the HTML you are loading the data into.

Comment: Updated it as requested

Comment: removing `<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/paycheck/scripts/currentMonth.php'); ?>` and then requesting the load does not display the data

Comment: Could the issue be that .load() will use GET unless an plainObject is given? Im not sure that GET would support the amount of html returned

Comment: Thank you for the help mate!